# When compiling a c++ script in VS Code, compiler gives no error, while compiling it with CodeBlocks gives few errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, codeblocks

That's the code I'm working on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    int a = rand() % 6 + 1;
    int b = rand() % 6 + 1;
    int c = rand() % 6 + 1;
    cout << "a: " << a <<" b: " << b <<" c: " << c << endl;

    if(a < b && a < c){
        cout << a << " is the lower" << endl;
    }
    else if(b < c){
        cout << b << " is the lower" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << c << " is the lower" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with VS CODE program shows the result without errors.

When I try to run the code with CodeBlocks compiler print the following message:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\****1_2.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\****1_2.cpp|15|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|
C:\****1_2.cpp|15|error: 'srand' was not declared in this scope|
C:\****1_2.cpp|17|error: 'rand' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: could be related to the toolchain configuration. Try to create an empty project from SetupWizad of CodeBlocks and see if it works. Than just copy your code in it.

Comment: "error: 'nullptr' was not declared" sounds like the compiler is not configured to use C++11 (or later).

Comment: `C:\`` makes me think that you are on Windows and therefore it can be good idea to use a normal Visual Studio instead. It will offer compilation toolchain out of box.

Comment: I think this is a CodeBlocks issue, you have to select the compiler you want to use for your project. Also, you have to make sure that you have created a c++ project and not c. I haven't used CodeBlocks in ages, hope that helps